# Delete unmanaged file after download?

Tags: files

In a custom module I create a file and then use `drupal_goto` to download it. How can I delete the file after it is downloaded? Placing a `file_unmanaged_delete` after the `drupal_goto` doesn't get executed, and `hook_file_download` happens before the download for permissions checks and such. So I'm not sure how to do this. Do I have to resort to cleaning up files in a folder with cron somehow?

Comment: Use file transfer and file delete function instead.

Comment: @Shabir Could you post an example of this or give more info? I don't understand yet

Comment: Does the answer solve the issue?

Comment: @Shabir I did not get it to work. I am also uncomfortable using those low-level php functions, and drupal_add_http_header just doesn't seem like a good solution. As a workaround to not having a post-download hook or another callback somewhere, I've created these files in a special directory that I just wipe with hook_cron.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove the file after download considering that your file is located in the *tmp* directory.

```php
$filename = 'foobar.xls';
$temp_path = realpath(file_directory_temp()) . '/';
if (file_exists($temp_path . $filename)) {
  // Serve file download.
  drupal_add_http_header('Pragma', 'public');
  drupal_add_http_header('Expires', '0');
  drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . basename($temp_path . $filename) . ';');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Length', filesize($temp_path . $filename));
  readfile($temp_path . $filename);
  unlink($temp_path . $filename);
  drupal_exit();
}
```